# Не запускается код c библиотекой Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Решил написать бота для дискорда на Python. Но он просто не запускается.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "token"

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=('+'))
bot.remove_command( 'help' )

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Я запущен!")

@bot.command()
async def Hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hi')

@bot.command()
async def test1(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Привет всем!",
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def lolzsait(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Тык для перехода",
        description="Ссылка для перехода на lolz",
        url='https://lolz.guru',
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Но при запуске выводит ошибку:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.ext'; 'discord' is not a package
```

[Клип](https://clips.twitch.tv/FancyTalentedHorseCopyThis-3R5-NydhXcTUibsF)

Хотя я все библиотеки установил. Что делать?

Comment: Что за файл `discord.py` у вас лежит в той же директории с вашим файлом? Это же явно не файл библиотеки. Ошибка происходит из-за того, что python обращается к вашему файлу, а не к библиотеке, при вызове `import discord`. Просто переименуйте файл `discord.py` на что-нибудь другое